# What's the price for MacMini compared to PC alternative

Tags: mac, microsoft-virtual-pc

http://www.apple.com/macmini/features.html

How much a PC with the same feature would cost if I buy a PC, and the detail. I want the same specs.

Comment: This website isn't really for shopping recommendations.. Can't you just find an alternative site and plug in the numbers?

Comment: Even if I want to do the research my self, why shouldn't I ask here first and then answer my own question. Why do research my self JUST for my self, if I can benefit many people with one research

Comment: Because that is not what this website is for, not "a shopping or buying recommendation"

Comment: I am not asking for shopping or buying recommendation. I want to compare price of Mac vs PC. So many people claim that Mac is overprice. I want to know how overprice mac typically is.

Comment: This question was closed 20 days ago..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK...
Depends where you live?
Alienware X51 is about the same size... but uses desktop CPUs and RAM
http://www.dell.com/us/p/alienware-x51/fs
If you want to save heaps, build it yourself, it's not that hard
To build it yourself:
[Case](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16811163149&Tpk=sugo%20sg05)
[Motherboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157238)
[Drive](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16822148701)
[CPU](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16819115073)
[RAM](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231424)
This will beat the **highest specced** Mac mini you can buy in any benchmark and it uses desktop parts.

Comment: Good what's the price comparisson?

Answer (score 2):

It would cost nothing as you can't buy a PC with the same features.

For example, you can't **legally** run OS X on it. One may argue which OS is better, but you are asking for the same features. Also the [Thunderbolt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_%28interface%29) that the Mini has. There is only 1 PC with Thunderbolt listed in the Wikipedia page and that's an ultraportable, not even the same form factor.

Most likely you are looking for a PC with similar form factor and similar specs. But that's what not what you asked.

Answer (score 1):

Your question does not require any knowledge or information that you cannot get easily yourself.  Simply visit any number of websites that allow you to customize a PC online, and choose the options that match the specifications of the Mac Mini.  The site will then present you with the price of the PC.
Here are three sites to start you off.

http://www.ascendtech.us/

http://www.portatech.com/

http://sys.1stchoicememory.com/

Otherwise, if you do not want to do the work yourself, you are just being a bit lazy.  No insult or offense intended.  You just have all the information and tools at your fingertips.  This site is not just to make people do work you could easily do yourself.

Comment: Tried those 3.Very difficult to shop there.